# API how to pull player with playlist - does Spotify API support playlists?

Tags: api, spotify, playlist

If you try to embed an individual link, like if you pull an individual link, it pulls the player in our post viewer- however, this is not possible with a playlist. How do I fix this so I am able to play a playlist as if it were an individual link

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by **embedding** the Play-list:

```
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:ficodelic:playlist:6KEI3T9dx1qgE3xQMSNtZV&amp;view=coverart&amp;" width="252" height="330" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" id="SpotifyId"></iframe>
```

FI